# How to Align Unicode-Type Values of a Column?

Tags: python, unicode, printing, formatting, tuples

I have the following output containing two columns (line# and ID):

```
1 Q50331
2 P75247
3 P75544
4 P22446
5 P78027
6 P75271
7 P75176
8 P0ABB4
9 P63284
10 P0A6M8
11 P0AES4
12 P39452
13 P0A8T7
14 P0A698
```

How can I make the ID values of second column align at the top of each other, like the following:

```
1  Q50331
2  P75247
3  P75544
4  P22446
5  P78027
6  P75271
7  P75176
8  P0ABB4
9  P63284
10 P0A6M8
11 P0AES4
12 P39452
13 P0A8T7
14 P0A698
```

The problem I am facing is how to incorporate the solution to my code.  I tried to use python `tabulate`, but found this is not working properly since what I am printing: `row[0]` is a unicode from the tuple `row` (**See the following code**).

```
count = 0
for row in c:
        count += 1
        print count, row[0]
```

Any idea how can I incorporate tabulate or other methods to align the unicode-type values in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [alignment specifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
data = {
    1:'Q50331',
    2:'P75247',
    3:'P75544',
    4:'P22446',
    5:'P78027',
    6:'P75271',
    7:'P75176',
    8:'P0ABB4',
    9:'P63284',
    10:'P0A6M8',
    11:'P0AES4',
    12:'P39452',
    13:'P0A8T7',
    14:'P0A698',
    333:'P00bar'
}

length = len(str(max(data.keys())))+1

for k,v in data.items():
    print "{:<{}}{}".format(k, length, v)
```

**Output:**

```
1   Q50331
2   P75247
3   P75544
4   P22446
5   P78027
6   P75271
7   P75176
8   P0ABB4
9   P63284
10  P0A6M8
11  P0AES4
12  P39452
13  P0A8T7
14  P0A698
333 P00bar
```

I've created `length` which will contain the length of the max value from `data` keys, +1. Then I pass that `length` value to my alignment specifier, which in this case is **4**:

```
{:<4}{}
```

Comment: Do I have to put the data in `row` into a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You can use any data structure, you'll just have to adapt it. Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)